# How to use a string as the key in a setState call in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a method in which I am attempting to call a state value for through a string. Essentially, the string is "greeting" and the state value is greeting: "hello world".

However, since the variable is a string "greeting", I am not able to call this.state.greeting with it and it gives me undefined. How can I convert a string to a variable so that it can be used to call this.state in React? I have experimented with the eval() method but it has not seemed to work.

Comment: Can you include relevant code please?

Comment: Do you maybe mean that you have some variable like `var myVar = "greeting"` and you want to access `this.state[myVar]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this.state["greeting"]

Answer (score 1):

this.state['greeting'] should work

Answer (score 1):

You can access it with javascript object bracket notation like so:

```
var myObj = {
  'greeting': 'hello world'
};

var myKey = 'greeting';

console.log(myObj[myKey]);        // 'hello world'
```